# split multiple url in string java

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a String which contains multiple url inside like: "https://example.org,http://example.net". The URL will be splited by the comma sign ",".

Normally I can split them using the syntax: `split("\\s*,\\s*")` but the url might contain the comma sign so I would like to split them when I get the ",http" syntax in the URL, so I use: `split("\\s*,http\\s*")`, but then from my second URL the "http" will be get rid of my URL string.

Can any one give me a hint to split the URL here in my string? Thank you so much!

Comment: Use a lookahead, `split("\\s*,\\s*(?=http)")`

Comment: I see, thank you so much Wiktor!

Comment: But if you are dealing with URLs that can contain commas (is that even possible?), how do you know that you will never come across an URL that has `,http` somewhere in the middle?

Comment: yes, in my url they can contain comma, something like: https://example.org?key=value1,value2

Comment: You'll get in trouble then if your code ever has to deal with something like `http://foo.com?key1=value1,http=value2`. Unlikely maybe, but I'd think twice before I'd take that risk.

Comment: this would be one possibility, thank you for your hint ;)